# Como puedo agregar un contador a mi script

Tags: bash, script

Estoy trabajando sobre un script que obtiene información de un log llamado ip.txt y contiene lo siguiente:

```
192.168.7.x OK
192.168.9.x OK
192.168.5.x OK
```

Buscando ayuda, logre hacer que imprimiera un estado dependiendo de el archivo si todas las IP tienen "OK" entonces esta "BIEN" si alguna de las IP tiene algo diferente a "OK" entonces esta mal.

```
filename="/home/ip.log" 
while read -r line 
do
  readline=$line
  if [[ $readline = *"OK"* ]]
  then
  result_output="BIEN"
  else
  result_output="MAL"
  fi
done < <(tail -n "+2" $filename)
echo $result_output
```

Ahora me gustaría hacer que cuando la salida sea "MAL" determinar cuantas lineas fueron como un contador por ejemplo que al imprimir sea algo asi "5 MAL"

Lo que hice fue agregar:

```
filename="/home/ip.log" 
while read -r line 
do
  **var=0**
  readline=$line
  if [[ $readline = *"OK"* ]]
  then
  result_output="BIEN"
  else
  result_output="MAL"**"$((var++))"**
  fi
done < <(tail -n "+2" $filename)
echo $result_output
```

Pero esto lo unico que hace es imprimir es "0" al final de MAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptando un poco tú código

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="/home/ip.log" 
while read -r line 
do
    readline=$line

    if [[ $readline != *"OK"* ]]; then
        errores=$((errores + 1))
    fi
done < <(tail -n "+2" $filename)

if [[ $errores > 1 ]]; then
    echo "MAL; $errores"
else
    echo "BIEN"
fi
```

Lo que hacemos básicamente, es manejar un contador de errores, cuando en una línea no encontramos un `OK` sumamos uno a éste: `errores=$((errores + 1))`, luego simplemente, al finalizar el ciclo verificamos la cantidad de errores.

Por otro lado, vuelvo a sugerirte usar `awk`, más o menos como lo hice en tu anterior pregunta:

```
awk '$2 !~ /OK/ {error += 1} END {if(error > 0){print "MAL:", error}else{print "BIEN"}}' /home/ip.log
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, como bien mencionas al usar awk veo que tiene algunas ventajas ademas de verse mas simplificado.

Comment: @AdrianLicon, lo principal es resolver el problema, sin duda `awk` vale la pena, como se suele decir, es una de las "navajas suizas" de los sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción más reducida para escribir sería:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_LOG_FILE="./ip.log"
IP_LOG_FILE_OK="./ip_ok.log"
IP_LOG_FILE_NOPE="./ip_nope.log"

q_logs_total=$( { cat $IP_LOG_FILE; echo ''; } | wc -l | cut -d " " -f 1) 
# ^^^^^^ Supongo que no hay líneas vacías y cuento el total de líneas del archivo.
logs_ok=$( egrep '[[:space:]]OK$' $IP_LOG_FILE | tee $IP_LOG_FILE_OK )
# Busco el patrón " OK" y las coincidencias las guardo en un archivo logs_ok.log
logs_nope=$( egrep -v '[[:space:]]OK$' $IP_LOG_FILE | tee $IP_LOG_FILE_NOPE )
# Busco que NO cumpla el patrón " OK" y las coincidencias las guardo en un archivo 
# logs_nope.log
q_logs_ok=$( wc -l <<< "$logs_ok" )
q_logs_nope=$( wc -l <<< "$logs_nope" )
# Cuento la coincidencias de cada tipo de registro.
msg="Registros:$q_logs_total
logs_ok:$q_logs_ok
logs_nope:$q_logs_nope"
# Creo el mensaje de salida.

printf "$msg\n" | sed -r 's/(.*)(:)(.*)/\1\2|\3|/g' | column -t -s : 
# Doy formato para que el mensaje se agradable.
# echo "$msg" # O sólo pon esto, si quieres que sea basico.
```

Que, en un archivo de la forma:

```
192.168.1.x OK
192.168.2.x OK
192.168.3.x OK
192.168.4.x OK
192.168.5.x NOPE
192.168.6.x OK
192.168.7.x NOPE
192.168.8.x OK
192.168.9.x OK
192.168.10.x NOPE
```

Arrojaría esto.

```
$ ./make_logs.sh
Registros  |10|
logs_ok    |7|
logs_nope  |3|
```

Guardando los registros en dos archivos llamados "ip_ok.log" e "ip_nope.log", esto es por si son demasiadas ip's. Después de tener estos archivos, podrías leerlas con un paginador como `most` o `less`

Y estos archivos tendrán algo como:

```
$ head ip_*
==> ip_nope.log <==
192.168.5.x NOPE
192.168.7.x NOPE
192.168.10.x NOPE

==> ip_ok.log <==
192.168.1.x OK
192.168.2.x OK
192.168.3.x OK
192.168.4.x OK
192.168.6.x OK
192.168.8.x OK
192.168.9.x OK
```